# Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. This error pops up for IEEE Access Class

Tags: tables, ieeeaccess

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}%[H]
    \caption{Algorithms parameters}
    \label{tab:algo_par}
        \resizebox{8.25cm}{!} {%ajusta el tamaño del cuadro
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
            \hline
                 \textbf{Algorithm} &\textbf{Parameters}&\textbf{Values}\\\hline
GA  &Number of iterations&200\\
&&Population size&200\\
&&P_m&0.1\\
&&P_c&0.9\\
&&N &11\\\hline
BPSO    &Number of iterations&200\\
&&Swarm size&200\\
&&V_{max}&4\\
&&V_{min}&-4\\
&&W_i&2\\
&&C_1&0.4\\
&&C_2&2\\
&&N &11\\\hline
WDO&    Number of iterations&200\\
&&Population  size&200\\
&&dimMin&-5\\
&&dimMax&5\\
&&V_{min}&-0.3\\
&&V_{max}&0.3\\
&&RT&3\\
&&n&11\\
&&g&0.2\\
&&a &0.4\\\hline
BFO&    Number of iterations&200\\
&&N_e&24\\
&&N_r&5\\
&&N_c&5\\
&&N_p&30\\
&&N_s&2\\
&&C_i&0.01\\
&&P_{ed}&0.1\\
&&\(\theta  \)&0.1\\\hline
HGPDO&Same parameters as &Same values as of \\
&&of GA, PSO and WDO&GA, PSO and WDO \\\hline
            \end{tabular}
            }
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your `\tabular` line definition has only three columns, but most lines have four (separated by three `&`s).  Add another column to the specification, or remove the "extra" `&` at the beginning of lines where it isn't needed.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to adopting the [recommendation of Don Hosek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/595054/5001) to change all instances of `&&` to `&`, you also need to make sure that math mode is applied appropriately to the cells in column 2. Aligning the numbers in the third column on their explicit or implicit decimal markers would also seem desirable. Eliminating all vertical lines and using the macros of the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/) package in order to give the table a more open look is to be encouraged.

The following minimum working example employs the `IEEEtran` document class as I don't seem to have access to the `ieeeaccess` document class (pun intended).

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Algorithms parameters}
\label{tab:algo_par}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l >{$}l<{$} S[table-format=3.2] @{}}
\toprule
Algorithm & \textup{Parameters} & {Values} \\
\midrule
GA    &$Number of iterations$&200\\
      &$Population size$&200\\
      &P_m&0.1\\
      &P_c&0.9\\
      &N &11\\ 
\addlinespace
BPSO  &$Number of iterations$&200\\
      &$Swarm size$&200\\
      &V_{\max}&4\\
      &V_{\min}&-4\\
      &W_i&2\\
      &C_1&0.4\\
      &C_2&2\\
      &N &11\\ 
\addlinespace
WDO   &$Number of iterations$&200\\
      &$Population size$&200\\
      &$dimMin$&-5\\
      &$dimMax$&5\\
      &V_{\min}&-0.3\\
      &V_{\max}&0.3\\
      &RT&3\\
      &n&11\\
      &g&0.2\\
      &a &0.4\\ 
\addlinespace
BFO   &$Number of iterations$&200\\
      &N_e&24\\
      &N_r&5\\
      &N_c&5\\
      &N_p&30\\
      &N_s&2\\
      &C_i&0.01\\
      &P_{\mathrm{ed}}&0.1\\
      &\theta &0.1\\ 
\addlinespace
HGPDO & $Same as for GA,$ & {Same as for GA,} \\
      & $PSO and WDO$     & {PSO and WDO} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got too many `&`s on most of your lines. There should be one `&` between columns which, since you have three columns, means there should be no more than two `&`s on each line. My gut reaction glancing at the code is that every line beginning with `&&` should begin with `&` instead.